How to fix Error Code=-4 with SKPSMTPMessage
We have an application on Iphone/ ios developed with Xcode/swift.
In this one, we use SKPSMTP iOS to send mails.
Often we get the message:

"Optional(Error Domain=SKPSMTPMessageError Code=-4 "The connection to the server was interrupted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The connection to the server was interrupted., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try sending your message again later.})"

Is there a solution to fix this problem that bothers users?

I will try a solution given by Github Copilot with connectTimeout = 30 and I will come back to you and tell you if it worked properly
